# Runtime Error (C++) on LRU Cache Practice

Tags: c++, caching

So I was working on the LRU cache problem on Leetcode and in attempting to submit my solution on their site, got a runtime error with the following message:

Runtime Error
Last executed input:
1101,[set(253,668),set(202,206),set(1231,3177),get(465),get(1333),set(651,3249),set(453,2472),get(1050),set(145,881),set(1256,1320),set(342,1528),get(37),.......

The problem statement is:
Design and implement a data structure for Least Recently Used (LRU) cache. It should support the following operations: get and set.

get(key) - Get the value (will always be positive) of the key if the key exists in the cache, otherwise return -1.
set(key, value) - Set or insert the value if the key is not already present. When the cache reached its capacity, it should invalidate the least recently used item before inserting a new item.

I've used Xcode in order to test out my code using a LRU capacity of 3 and it gave me the expected behavior and I did not have this runtime error. I would really appreciate it if you could help me understand where I'm going wrong. Thank you so much in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class listNode {
public:
    listNode *prev;
    listNode *next;
    int key;
    int data;
};

class LRUCache{
public:
    LRUCache(int capacity) {
       this->capacity = capacity;
       this->currentSize = 0;
       tail = NULL;
       head = NULL;
    }

    int get(int key) {
        // If you can find the key
        if(cache.find(key) != cache.end()) {
            // Mark it as most recently used
            head->prev = cache[key];
            head = cache[key];
            cache[key]->prev = NULL;

            return cache[key]->data;

        }
        else {
             return -1;
        }
     }

     void set(int key, int value) {
     // If you can find the key
     if(cache.find(key) != cache.end()) {
         // Change the value
         cache[key]->data = value;
         return;
     }
     else {
         currentSize ++;

         // Create a new node and insert at the tail
         if (currentSize == 1) {
             listNode *node = new listNode();
             node->key = key;
             node->data = value;
             cache[key] = node;
             head = node;
             head->prev = NULL;
             head->next = NULL;
             tail = head;

             // No point in having a LRU cache with a maxSize of 0 so we're OK
         }
         else {

             listNode *node = new listNode();
             node->data = value;
             node->key = key;
             node->prev = tail;
             tail->next = node;
             node->next = NULL;
             tail = node;
             cache[key] = node;


             // Remove the most recently used item if we are at capacity
             if(currentSize > capacity) {
                 listNode *trash = head;
                 head = head->next;

                 cache.erase(trash->key);
                 delete trash;
             }
         }
         return;
     }
 }
private:
    int capacity;
    int currentSize;
    map<int, listNode*> cache;
    int mostRecentlyUsedKey;
    listNode *head; // Head is the most recently used
    listNode *tail;
};
```

Comment: Can we have a `main()`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: sadly not, Leetcode has their own testcode which I'm assuming uses this class.